# The correct community to ask a question about antenna modules used with Arduino (nRF24L01)

Tags: support, site-recommendation, closed-questions

What is the correct community to ask a question about antenna modules, more specifically, the nRF24L01 wireless module?

I asked [a question about the module's transmitter antenna gain and field strength](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/93508/whats-the-transmitter-antenna-gain-of-the-nrf24l01-module) in [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) because the module is usually used with Arduino. However, the question was closed because it is judged as off-topic.

Now I wonder where in Stack Exchange (or outside platforms) I should ask the question. I'm guessing [Electrical Engineering Community](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or [Physics Community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), but I would like to make sure as I would not like to mess up communities and also my heart hurts when my question is closed.

Comment: There seems to be quite a few questions about [nRF24L01](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=nRF24L01) on EE. Not sure if the specifics of your question are on topic though :v

Comment: side note: what's up with the related questions lol?

Comment: These kind of questions are on-topic at Electrical Engineering, but with some reservations. You cannot ask where to find/buy something there. In general ask about technologies over specific products. You'll also be expected to link the datasheet to the part you are asking about, since nobody will want to track that down on their own just to help you. That being said, I'm pretty sure your question as-is would be considered fine, just add a link to the datasheet and other relevant info like app notes etc.

Comment: Outside SE then you can try https://electrical.codidact.com/ but the scope is very similar to Electrical Engineering at Stack Exchange.

Comment: There is also [Ham.SE], I don't know that site other than an occasional HNQ but they have two existing posts about this antenna that are explicitly about using it with an Arduino, https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16645/bias-tee-for-hf-noise-and-losses and https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5554/low-power-long-distance-wireless-data-communication/6327#6327.

Comment: @MissSkooter: The unrelated "Related questions" were seemingly due to the [community] tag, which wasn't really appropriate for this question (as it's not asking about the community of users, but rather which site the question belonged on). I've removed it now.